# Is it possible for an onscroll event without content overflow?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that's formatted to exactly fit the window it's rendered in. When the user `"scrolls"`, I want to capture that and change the opacity + size of some of the elements... creating a `"scrolling IN"` effect, versus scrolling up/down or side to side.

Is that possible? From what I've been reading it seems like the only way an `"onscroll"` event will be triggered is if the page's content overflows the window.

I feel like there's probably a simple solution here and I'm just overlooking it. `>_<`

I'd love to be able to do this with just JavaScript, but if there's a plugin I can use to achieve the effect that's cool too. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolls" if there's nothing to scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`onmousewheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel) or [`onwheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/wheel?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference%2Fwheel)

Comment: I could kiss you. For posterity, here's an article describing exactly what I want to do: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/